# App crash when open EDIT dialog and rotate device

Tags: android, crash, rotation, android-activity, screen-rotation

I have a problem. When I click "ADD exercise" and open ADD dialog to put some info everything works good even when I rotate device. But when I rotate device with "EDIT dialog" the APP  is crashing
 Please, help me. 
Need something to prevent it. (I'm not programmer, so its not easy for me)

```
public class ShowExercisesListActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Exercises";

private List<Exercise> mExercises;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayAdapter<Exercise> mArrayAdapter;
private View mAddExerciseDialogLayout;
private Context mContext;
private EditText exerciseName;

private static final int DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE = 0;

 // package scope, since it is accessed in inner classes
WorkoutTrackerApp mApp;

/** 
 * Called when the activity is first created. 
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.type_list);

    mApp = (WorkoutTrackerApp) getApplication();
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mExercises = DBUtil.fetchAllExercises(this);

    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Exercise>(this, R.layout.type_list_item, mExercises) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row;

            if (null == convertView) {
                row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.type_list_item, null);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }

            Exercise type = (Exercise) mExercises.get(position);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(type.getName());

            return row;
        }

    };
    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    //dialog box layout
    mContext = this;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mAddExerciseDialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_type_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.type_layout_root));



    exerciseName = (EditText) mAddExerciseDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.type_name);
    //register for context menu
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());      

    if (mExercises.size() == 0) {
        // if there are no exercises initially, then show the add type dialog
        showDialog(DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE);            
    }



    //Начало:Активация кнопки "Добавить упражнение"
    Button addExerciseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_add_exercise);
    addExerciseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mApp.setCurrrentDialogStatus(DialogStatus.ADD);
            showDialog(DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE);
        }
    });
    //Конец: Активация кнопки "Добавить упражнение"


    //Начало:Активация иконки Верхней плашки
    ImageButton GoHomeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    GoHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent5 = new Intent(ShowExercisesListActivity.this, AndroidApp.class);
            ShowExercisesListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent5);
        }
    });
    //Конец:Активация иконки Верхней плашки
}






@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Exercise type = mExercises.get(position);
    Log.v(TAG, "Clicked " + type.getName() + "Id: " + type.getId());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            TabWidget.class);
    intent.putExtra("typeId", type.getId());
    startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * When the context menu is created
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu, android.view.View, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)
 */
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.exercise_context_menu, menu);
}



/**
 * When a context menu item is selected
 *  
 * @see android.app.Activity#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.edit_exercise:
        //Edit Exercise name
        mApp.setCurrentExerciseDialogStatus(DialogStatus.EDIT);         
        editExercise((int) info.id);
        return true;
    case R.id.delete_exercise:
        //Delete Exercise and all its entries
        deleteExercise((int) info.id);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.types_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add_exercise:
        mApp.setCurrentExerciseDialogStatus(DialogStatus.ADD);
        showDialog(DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE);
        break;

    case R.id.home: // Go Back to local website
        Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(ShowExercisesListActivity.this, AndroidApp.class);
        ShowExercisesListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent3);
        return true;

    case R.id.close: // Close WebView
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent); 
        return true;
    case R.id.google: // Open new WebView with the e.g. Google Url
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://vk.com/gymtraining")));

        return true;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateDialog(int)
 */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        //build the dialog
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(mAddExerciseDialogLayout);
        builder.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.add_exercise_title))
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton(this.getString(R.string.add, this.getString(R.string.exercise)), null)
           .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });

        dialog = builder.create();

        break;

    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onPrepareDialog(int, android.app.Dialog)
 */
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
    Button positiveButton = null;

    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE:

        switch (mApp.getCurrentExerciseDialogStatus()) {
        case DEFAULT:
        case ADD:

            alertDialog.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.add_exercise_title));
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, this.getString(R.string.add, this.getString(R.string.exercise)), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       //Insert the new data into db
                       String typeName = exerciseName.getText().toString();
                       Exercise newExercise = DBUtil.insertExercise(mContext, typeName);

                       Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.exercise_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       mArrayAdapter.add(newExercise);
                       mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
               });

            positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setText(this.getString(R.string.add, this.getString(R.string.exercise)));
            positiveButton.invalidate();

            exerciseName.setText("");

            break;

        case EDIT:
            alertDialog.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.edit, this.getString(R.string.exercise)));
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, this.getString(R.string.edit_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       //Update the data into db
                        Exercise exerciseToEdit = (Exercise) exerciseName.getTag(); 
                        exerciseToEdit.setName(exerciseName.getText().toString());

                        DBUtil.updateExercise(mContext, exerciseToEdit);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.exercise_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }

               });

            Exercise exerciseToEdit = (Exercise) exerciseName.getTag();
            exerciseName.setText(exerciseToEdit.getName());

            positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setText(this.getString(R.string.edit_button));
            positiveButton.invalidate();

            break;
            }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * Edit Exercise name
 * 
 * @param id
 */
private void editExercise(int position) {
    exerciseName.setTag(mExercises.get(position));
    showDialog(DIALOG_ADD_EXERCISE);
}

/**
 * Delete an Exercise
 * 
 * @param position
 */
private void deleteExercise(int position) {
    Exercise exercise = mExercises.get(position);
    DBUtil.deleteExercise(mContext, exercise.getId());

    Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.exercise_deleted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

    mArrayAdapter.remove(exercise);
    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Comment: you should post logcat error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't go over the whole code right now but if your problem is only when you rotate the phone and it is not necessary to have the rotation activated, then why don't you just add either of the following lines into your activity definition in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```